# SwiftUI transition with related animation

Tags: swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI and I'm trying to  make a simple animation working. Here is what I want:
A single button on the screen, when it is clicked, some text shows up.

I'm using `AnyTransition.offset` and `AnyTransition.animation` api to control the animation to delay 5 seconds. But it shows up once I clicked. well if I change `AnyTransition.offset` to `AnyTransition.opacity` it starts to work. Why? Here is the code, very simple.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var show = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            
            if show {
                Text("AAAA")
                    .transition(
                        AnyTransition
                            .offset(x: 100, y: 100)
                            //                            .opacity
                            .animation(
                                Animation
                                    .easeInOut(duration: 1)
                                    .delay(5)
                        )
                )
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button("Click") {
                self.show.toggle()
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here is what I want: A single button on the screen, when it is
> clicked, some text shows up.

Why make it so complicated? Just use an `opacity` modifier that checks the state and follow that with an `animation`.

See here:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var show = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            
            //Opacity that checks if show is true/ false and an animation on the text
            Text("AAAA").opacity(self.show ? 1 : 0).animation(.easeIn)
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button("Click") {
                self.show.toggle()
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }

}
```

Produces this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be a container that animates content when it's removed or added. So here is a possible solution for your transition.

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

```
VStack {
    if show {
        Text("AAAA")
            .transition(
                AnyTransition
                    .offset(x: 100, y: 100)
    //                            .opacity
        )
    }
}
.animation(Animation
            .easeInOut(duration: 1)
            .delay(1)     // decreased for testing
)
```

Comment: why opacity works in my original code but offset does not?